# MVC3 Validation on edit

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am having a problem with my client side validating. I am using DataAnnotations in my model. An this works when i am in the create form very nicely, but when i go to edit the information only some of the validation works.

i.e the Name box does have clientside val but the amount box does.

i have check the source name doesnot include the data-val="true". I don't understand why this would render this way because on the 'create' form it does and works fine?

```
<input class="text-box single-line" id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value="name" />
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Name" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Amount must be a number." data-val-required="The Amount field is required." id="Amount" name="Amount" type="text" value="120.00" />
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Amount" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

can somebody give me an idea how to make my 'edit' page validation work?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the help. but is have solved it!!

The problem was that because i was generated the edit view from the wrong class which meant that the DataAnnotations was not being read. what is have done now is to change the name of the class to that of my database then mark the class as partial and connected the DataAnnotaions by using this code below

[MetadataType(typeof(Budget_Validation))]
    public partial class Budget
I put all the dataAnnotaions in the Budget_Validation class.

All now working fine!

Thanks